# density of spaces, Lebesgue

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

My question is the following: 
Is the space $C^\infty(\bar{G})$ dense in $L^\infty(G)$ ? 
Assume that $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
I know this result holds, if we have $G$ instead of $\bar{G}$.
But is it true here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in most reasonable cases. Here is an particular example illustrating the fenomena:

You cant approximate $\operatorname{sign}\in L_\infty([-1,1])$ function by smooth functions in $\sup$ norm because this would imply that uniform limit of countinuous functions is discontinuous, which is well known to be untrue.

Comment: what about the space $W^{1,2}(G) \cap C^\infty(\bar{G})$. Is this dense in $W^{1,2}(G) \cap L^\infty(G)$ ?

Comment: @franca wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Approximation_by_smooth_functions) that $C^\infty(\overline{G})$ is a dense subset of $W^{k,p}(G)$ so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @Norbert's comment: This is not true. $W^{1,2} \cap L^\infty$ contains discontinuous functions, which *can not* be approximated uniformly with continuous functions.

Comment: @gerw, you read my thoughts, thank you for clarification

Comment: but the result in my comment is true?

Comment: @franca It is not dense.